# Best way to store 500 marker objects in DOM

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, here-api

I'm implementing a nokia/google map and I have to store 500 markers in it. I receive the information (name, lat, lon, markergroup and image) by looping through a php array and putting it into an unordered list using data-attributes. Then I'm using jQuery to loop through those li elements and fill the map with marker information.

This just works fine but having a list with 500 hidden elements inside the dom seems to be an overhead for me concerning performance issues.

Before the markers had been inserted directly into the map using inline javascript combined with the php elements which was a bad practice for me since I have to use the map in different situations and I had a lot of duplicated code.

Now is there a better way to archive this than having 500 dom elements containing the required marker information?

Some thoughts:

1) I could create a JSON array containing all the 500 marker information and save it inside a single data attribute. Not sure if there are some browser limitations cause this is a huge amount of data for a single data-attribute. Also the performance might be even worse due to the json encode/decode.

2) I could create a JSON/XML/KML file with the required marker information and access this through AJAX. This is a bigger effort in my case and the ajax request might take longer than the dom parsing.

3) Use inline JS again (really a bad practice in my case due to the lack in reusable code..)

Any thoughts? Did someone test a similar case checking the performance?

Comment: you could just do this as either inline javascript (which is not pretty, but used a lot) or indeed by using an ajax request that loads asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Output json directly into a script tag is the easiest option:

```
<script>
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($data);?>;
</script>
```

But ajax is also a simple with jquery:

```
var data;
$.get('somefile.php', function(data){
    data=data;
});
```

somefile.php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I decided to go with the script tag since it's better than having 500 dom elements and it's the fastest way to do what I like to do even tho I think ajax might be the better approach. Anyway, your code inside the script tag is incorrect. The quotes should be removed since json_encode already provides valid json data which is an object and should not be surrounded by quotes. Thanks for the answer tho

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some options here and you already got some them in your mind.
In my humble opinion, AJAX is the most semantic option and will give you less problems in future.

For performance you can try reduce the [repaint](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle) events.
Consider hide the entire map before add 500 markers and show them when that is finished.

For usability, you can show a loading gif, for instance.

It already saved me a lot.

As @DoXicK said, if your markers are a static content, you can use a [JSONP](http://www.webcodegeeks.com/javascript/getting-started-with-json-p) strategy importing a script tag in your body.